# I really need to know the Chinese characters preferably handwritten to the phrase “pursuit of happiness”

Tags: traditional-characters

I really need this translation into handwritin characters for a tattoo. It’s really hard to find an accurate website for “pursuit of happiness”

Answer (score 1):

> *It’s really hard to find an accurate website for “pursuit of happiness”*

Google Translate's result 追求幸福 is accurate

As for Chinese Handwriting fonts, you can look for them on the web

I selected a few fonts on my computer as examples of what you can expect

[image]

Answer (score 1):

追求幸福
the pursuit of happiness (catch it and it's gone!)

"contained in the introduction to the Declaration of Independence, the statement announcing that, in 1776, the 13 American colonies were now independent and no longer under British rule."

(Really only applicable to those of Anglo-Saxon descent, even now, 200+ years later)

We hold these truths to be self-evident,
我们认为这些真理是不言而喻的，
that all men are created equal,
所有的人都是平等的，
that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights,
他们被造物主赋予了某些不可剥夺的权利，
that among these are Life,
其中包括生命、
Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness.
自由和追求幸福。